# IOS Continuous Updates for XCFramework

Tags: ios, continuous-deployment, cicd, xcframework

I am building a XCFramework for my company and the primary purpose is to expose our data for clients using this Framework. Clients can access data using this Framework through use-cases without knowing the implementation details.
This Framework needs a very high run-time maintenance support as we may have to add or update the use-cases based on clients requests or changing busing requirements. It's very important to design an automated solution to deploy new changes and make the updated Framework available for clients. I'm looking to host SDK somewhere so I can build and deploy it. Something like maven for Android. But I've not found some good solution yet.
I would love to hear if someone has similar experience or if someone can guide for a better solution. Thanks